# ionic launchNavigator open google map with direction

Tags: google-maps, ionic-framework, ionic4, ionic-native

I facing a problem with an ionic in open google map but not show the Direction button. it shows the only route. I want to Direction with my location. my code is for open google map is

ionic version is 5

```
let options: LaunchNavigatorOptions = {
   
    start:"21.078093,72.885990",
    startName:"driving",
   
   
  }
this.launchNavigator.navigate([22.289096,73.256244], options
     );
```

[image: Open google map like this]

Comment: I also use this code in my app. But in my map show the navigate button. Code is same. But I don,t use "startName" in my code.

Comment: let options: LaunchNavigatorOptions = {
      start: this._location,
    };

    this.launchNavigator
      .navigate("6.822704617078841, 79.88849870416693", options)
      .then(
        (success) => console.log("Launched navigator"),
        (error) => console.log("Error launching navigator", error)
      );

Comment: I want to three locations it means user location and we define routes of two location points